# Is the usage of “does no longer exist” grammatically correct?

Tags: existential-constructions

Example: This Facebook member does no longer exist. 
Is it grammatically correct to add “does” in front of no longer exist or is it only correct to say that “it no longer exists” or “it does no longer exist”?

Comment: This Facebook member no longer exists.

Comment: But is it fine to use “does no longer exist”

Comment: Using "does", perhaps "This Facebook member does not exist." Is there any way of telling if the person *ever* had a Facebook account?

Comment: You can say 'does not exist any longer', but, as Lawrence says in his answer, you can only use 'does no longer exist' if you are using 'does' as an intensifier. It's not a usual order of words.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's grammatical, but it is used in a restricted context. It recasts "no longer exist" as a positive statement, in the sense of the following question and answer:

- Q: Does he no longer exist on Facebook?
- A: Yes, he does no longer exist on Facebook.

[*Does* acts as an intensifier](http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=21366), but in this context, it gives 'positive' emphasis to "no longer exist", rather than 'negative' emphasis to "exist".

> **do** *auxiliary verb*
>   3 Used to give emphasis to a positive verb.
>   ‘I do want to act on this’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/do)